# REGEX: how to match the syntax ?

Tags: c++, regex, syntax, c++11

I have a Bug at my simple REGEX. 
I have been trying to write some simple regular expressions at C++ using `std::regex`. Here is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::string str = "Hello world";
    std::regex rx("\w+\s\w+"), rx2("ello");
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::regex_match(str.begin(), str.end(), rx) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::regex_search(str.begin(), str.end(), rx2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This program should print (according to a tutorial)

```
true
true
```

but it prints

```
false
false
```

Where am I making a mistake? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I'm using `g++ -std=c++0x %file.cpp% -o %file%` if it helps

Comment: Are you using GCC? If so, switch to boost.regex, because `<regex>` is not really implemented on it.

Comment: Works with clang++/libc++, and throws with g++/libstdc++. Both do not print 'false false'.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to escape the backslashes in there?

Comment: @Joey: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes, Unless you're using raw string literals, the backslash is used for certain characters like a newline (`'\n'`), so to get a backslash, you need two: `'\\'`.

Comment: @Joey: you mean that --> "\\w+\\s\\w+"

Comment: Either that or `R"(\w+\s\w+)"`.

Comment: Both cause `std::regex_error`

Comment: To repeat what @R.MartinhoFernandes said, **[`<regex>` is unimplemented](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631)** in GCC

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned I use **g++**

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes: GCC (all caps) is the Gnu Compiler Collection, of which g++ is a part. I.e., it's not implemented in g++.

Comment: Do you know any compilers that support `std::regex`?

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes libc++ (Clang Standard C++ library) and MSVC (I think since 2010, for 2008 it was in the `tr1::` namespace). And of course there is the boost version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated g++ (GCC) does not have a proper implementation for regex (it is unimplemented but still compiles).

The [Boost library](http://boost.org) has an implementation for regexes that is almost completely compatible with regexes in C++11. You could use that with minimal changes in your code (just using boost:: instead of std::).

Here is a code that compiles and works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::string str = "Hello world";
    boost::regex rx("\\w+\\s\\w+"), rx2("ello");
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << boost::regex_match(str.begin(), str.end(), rx) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << boost::regex_search(str.begin(), str.end(), rx2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have also fixed missing escapes for the backslashes for rx because it does not work without it.

To compile this you have to install libboost-regex-dev package (or something similar if not using Ubuntu/Debian) and execute this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -lboost_regex -o test
```